# Bind default props to component at render time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am curious if React allows you to set a few default props on a component that you don't own.

Say, you have a `TextField` component, and you want to make sure everytime you use a TextField in this given project, you are passing in the `hasFloatingLabel={true}` prop.

I'm sure this code won't work, but, is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
import { TextField as CCTextField } from '@MyCompany/core-components'

export const TextField = CCTextField.bind({
  hasFloatingLabel: true
})
```

It's like, I'm interested in a special form a `.bind` which allows defaulting some 'props', and having those act as my own custom defaults.

...In theory, this could be achieved through globals, but that would never get through code review. (`function foo({bar = window.fooDefaults.bar}) {}`

> I supposed a simple option would be to create a "wrapper" component.

For the sake of this question, lets say I want a 1-3 line bit of code to setup several default props on a component. So, you could do something like this inside of any render function:

```
import { TextField as CCTextField } from '@MyCo/core-components'

const FunctionalComponentFoo = ({a, b, c}) => {

  // ...calls a series of hooks...

  // Would this work??
  const TextField = (props) => CCTextField({
    hasFloatingLabel: true,
    placeholder: ' ',
    severalMoreFieldsA: a,
    severalMoreFieldsB: b,
    severalMoreFieldsC: c,
    id: 'idPrefix_' + props.name,
    ...props
  })

  // ...not really a simple component...

  return (
    <div className="one">
      <div className="two">
        <TextField name="firstName" />
      </div>
      <div className="three">
        <TextField name="lastName" />
      </div>
      <TextField name="address1" />
      <TextField name="address2" />
    </div>
    {/* ... many more fields ... */}
  )
}
```

As you could imagine, repeating these props into every TextField would make the component quite big+long.

I'm also not interested in using prop spreading (`{...defaultProps}`, because it adds another line to each `<TextField` call.

Answer (score 1):

Although it sounds interesting, I wouldn't go down this road.
Instead, I'd create a wrapper element which will pass whatever props I want, and expose it.
If your project is well organised, it shouldn't be a problem.

```
import { TextField as CCTextField } from '@MyCompany/core-components'

export const TextField = props => <CCTextField hasFloatingLabel={true} {...props} />
```

Or simply by binding the default props to this component reguallarly.

Comment: should {...props} be after hasFoatingLabel so you can still turn it off if u want to?